# Можно ли с помощью Arrays.sort(…) отсортировать массив «наших» объектов?

Tags: java

Столкнулся с таким вот вопросом из списка на подготовку к собеседованию на junior java и не могу раздуплиться никак.

Comment: Определив компаратор, предполагаю что можно

Comment: @rastorguev.i.a [Вот](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/) отличные примеры.

Comment: Moжно. Только вы не указали какие объекты и как вы их хотите отсортировать.

Comment: Можно если определен соответствующий интерфейс. Если его нет, то можно создать анонимный класс прямо на месте.